# update in redshift table

Tags: sql, sql-update, amazon-redshift

I have a very weird problem with a table in redshift, below are the steps that I took :

```
   1 : Alter table_name add columns flag integer
    /* table_name row count 10000*/
   2 :update table_name set
   flag = 1 
   where/* some condition*/
   -----rows affected 4000

3.update table_name set
flag = 0
where flag<> 1
 ----rows affected 0
```

When I select from table_name where flag = 1 I get 4000 then why the remaing 6000 are not getting updated?
Can anyone explain logic behind this? Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 4):

Because  `flag` can also be `null` and to compare with `null` you need the `is` operator (or a NULL save unequal operator which some DB engines provide)

```
update table_name 
set flag = 0
where flag is null or flag <> 1
```